# Parsing xml string in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I have the following xml string:

```
<AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult>
    <SubjectFromWebIdentityToken>us-east-1:xxxx</SubjectFromWebIdentityToken>
    <Audience>us-east-1:xxxxxxxx</Audience>
    <AssumedRoleUser>
      <Arn>arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx/xxxxxx</Arn>
      <AssumedRoleId>xxxx</AssumedRoleId>             
    </AssumedRoleUser>
    <Credentials>      
      <SessionToken>xxxxxx</SessionToken>
      <SecretAccessKey>xxxxx</SecretAccessKey>
      <Expiration>2015-02-03T15:26:03Z</Expiration>
      <AccessKeyId>xxxxxxx</AccessKeyId>
    </Credentials>
    <Provider>xxxxx</Provider>
  </AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>xxxxxx</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse>
```

I would like to retrieve the SessionToken within the `<Credentials>` node

I tried the following:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(response);
var root = xdoc.Root.Element("AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse");
```

but the variable root is returning null.

How do I retrieve the SessionToken from the `<Credentials>` node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made two mistakes:

- There's no `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse` element *under* the root element; it *is* the root element
- The `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse` element is in a namespace (`https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/"`) so you need to specify that when you call `Element` or anything similar. All the descendant elements inherit that namespace too, unless they specify something different.

So for example:

```
XNamespace ns = https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/";
var root = xdoc.Root;
var result = root.Element(ns + "AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult");
```

To get the `SessionToken` from the `Credentials` tag, you could either be very specific:

```
var token = root.Element(ns + "AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult")
                .Element(ns + "Credentials")
                .Element(ns + "SessionToken")
                .Value;
```

Or just use `Descendants`:

```
var token = root.Descendants(ns + "SessionToken").Single().Value;
```

Either way, it's using the namespace which is the important part.

Comment: okay @Jon Skeet, got that. The challenge is how to get the SessionToken from the Credentials Tag, I did this: result.Element("Credentials").Element("SessionToken").ToString() and got Access Violation Exception